# i can't understand why my code doesn't work can someone please check it out? I am very new (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, function, checkbox

This is the script :

```
<script>
var a,b,c;
a = document.getElementById("myCheck1");
b = document.getElementById("myCheck2");
c = document.getElementById("myCheck3");
```

This function works only if the other one is a comment :

```
function check() { 
if (a.checked == true)
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="a true";
else
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML="a false";

if (b.checked == true)
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="b true";
else
document.getElementById("b").innerHTML="b false";

if (c.checked == true)
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="c true";
else
document.getElementById("c").innerHTML="c false";
}
```

This function doesnt work and  make the other one not to work :

```
function clickOnB() {
if (a.checked == true || c.checked == true)
a.checked = false;
c.checked = false;
else
b.checked = true;
}
</script>
```

This is the body :

```
Checkbox1: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" value="a"/>
Checkbox2: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="clickOnB() " 
value="b"/>
Checkbox3: <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" value="c"/>
<p id="a"></p>
<p id="b"></p>
<p id="c"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="check()" />
```

I can't understand why my code doesn't work can someone please check it out? I am very new (JavaScript)

Comment: The title should give a short summary of the problem and not contain unrelevant information

Comment: The console will tell you that there is a syntax error in your code -> [`if ... else ...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax problem in your function:

This

```
function clickOnB() {
    if (a.checked == true || c.checked == true)
        a.checked = false;
    c.checked = false; //Not in the if because of missing brackets
    else //Syntax error
    b.checked = true;
}
```

should be

```
function clickOnB() {
    if (a.checked == true || c.checked == true) {
        a.checked = false;
        c.checked = false;
    } else {
        b.checked = true;
    }
}
```

If you do not specify brackets on an `if` condition, only the following command (until the next semicolon) will be evaluated in case the `if` condition evaluates `true`. Because you want to have multiple commands be executed in that case you need to use brackets.

Comment: Hello Thomas, welcome to StackOverflow :-) I have edited your answer in connection with a *First Post Review* and changed mainly three things: I rephrased the question *"Should this not be ...?"* to a statement, because (you are right and) an answer should only be posted if you know that what you do is correct. A question as an answer is therefore always wrong and might get deleted. I also removed the part in which you ask the author to use the browser debugger, because it is a comment to the original question and does not belong to an answer. At last I added an explanation.